# Fortran 90 setting up a directory

Tags: directory, fortran

I'm working on a Fortran 90 based program called GULP and I'm trying to edit a .F file by having it direct to my Force 2.0 compiler. I want to know if I'm using the right syntax. I inserted what I thought the directory was in the Darwin section (I'm using Windows 7). Windows said the file path was: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Force 2.0

```
makedir()
{
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ]
    then
         mkdir "$dir"
    fi
    cd $dir
}

debug=
if [ "$1" = "-debug" ]
then
  debug="_DEBUG"
  shift
fi
os=`uname -s`
case $os in
#
# Mac OS-X using Absoft compiler
#
  Darwin)  dir="\Program Files (x86)\Force 2.0"
       makedir
       if [ "$debug" = "" ]
       then
           echo 'OPT=-O' > makefile
           echo 'OPT1=-O' >> makefile
           echo 'BAGGER=' >> makefile
       else 
           echo 'OPT=' > makefile
           echo 'BAGGER=-g ' >> makefile
   fi
       target=${1}_
       echo 'RUNF90=force 2.0' >> makefile
       echo 'FFLAGS=-I.. -DLINUX ' >> makefile
       echo 'LIBS=' >> makefile
       echo 'GULPENV=' >> makefile
       echo 'DEFS=-DLINUX' >> makefile
       ;;
```

Comment: What are your problems? Did you get some error message? What exactly did you do with the script above?

Comment: The problem is probably that you haven't double quoted `$dir`, try using `cd "$dir"`